# returning python data as a json object after get request

Tags: python

I have a python AWS lambda function which gets data from a database.  The function is triggered by an API gateway endpoint.  I am having trouble returning the data back to api gateway.

My python function

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="xxxx", password="xxxx",
                                  host="xxxx", port="xxxx",
                                  database="xxxx")
                                  
    earlydate = json.dumps(event['queryStringParameters']['earlyDate'])
    laterdate = json.dumps(event['queryStringParameters']['laterdate'])
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    postgres_get_query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE time > '{0}' and time < '{1}'".format(earlydate, laterdate)
    cursor.execute(postgres_get_query)
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': records
    }
```

I am able to print the records and verify the function works.  I have also been able to change the `records` variable with a string and I can successfully return that.  I can't figure out how to format my return statement so that the body contains the response of my database call.

Comment: have you tried `'body': json.dumps(records)` ?

Comment: I have. That doesn't work unfortunately.